# Make simple plot nicer with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, plot

Is there a way to make this figure to ***look nicer***?

For instance, how to write the legends of the red arrows or the spacing of the dashed black lines?

At least for me, it is quite crude and can be improved..but I don't know how

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
        % ladder
        \draw[thick] (-1.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
        \draw[thick] (-1.5, .7) -- (2.5, .7);
        \draw[thick,dashed] (-2, 0) -- (-1.5, 0);
        \draw[thick,dashed] (2.5, 0) -- (3, 0);
        \draw[thick,dashed] (-2, .7) -- (-1.5, .7);
        \draw[thick, dashed] (2.5, .7) -- (3, .7);
        
        % hopping
        \draw [thick, dashed,  red] (0.5,0) to (.5,.7);
        \draw [thick, dashed, red] (2.05,0) to [out=40,in=-40]  (2.05,.7);
        \draw [thick, dashed, red] (1.95,.7)  to [out=-140,in=-220] (1.95,0) ;
        \draw [thick, dashed, red] (-1,0) -- (-1,.7);
        
        % arrow J_jos
        \draw [thick, -stealth] (0.5,-0.15) -- (0.4,0.15);
        \draw [thick, -stealth] (0.55,0.15) -- (0.65,-0.15);
        \draw [thick, red] (0.4,0.33) -- (.5,0.43);
        \draw [thick, red] (.5,0.43) -- (.6,0.33);
        
        % arrow t_\perp
        \draw [thick, red] (-1.1,0.33) -- (-1,0.43);
        \draw [thick, red] (-1,0.43) -- (-.9,0.33);
        
        % arrow J_superexchange
        \draw [thick, -stealth]  (1.95,0.15) -- (2.05,-0.15);
        \draw [thick, -stealth] (2.05,0.55) -- (1.95,0.85);
        \draw [thick, red] (2.1,0.3) -- (2.2,0.4);
        \draw [thick, red] (2.2,0.4) -- (2.3,0.3);
        \draw [thick, red] (1.7,0.4) -- (1.8,0.3);
        \draw [thick, red] (1.8,0.3) -- (1.9,0.4);
        
        % arrow t_perp
        \draw [thick, -stealth]  (-.95,-0.15) -- (-1.05,0.15);
        
        % name hoppigs
        \node[] at (-1,1.2) {a)};
        \node[] at (-0.8,0.35) {t};
        \draw [] (-0.75,0.2) -- (-0.6,0.2);
        \draw [] (-0.675,0.2) -- (-0.675,0.35);
        
        \node[] at (.5,1.2) {b)};
        \node[] at (0.7,.35) {t};
        \node[] at (0.9,.4) {\scriptsize pair};
        
        \node[] at (2,1.2) {c)};
        \node[] at (2.5,.35) {t};
        \node[] at (2.7,.4) {\scriptsize sing};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Schematic representations of the possible instabilities. (a) Due to the transverse coupling, we can end up with a simultaneous hop of particles. (b) Two particles bound in the same site hop together in the transverse direction (Josephson hopping of pair). (c) The particles hop simultaneously by swapping their positions (super-exchange or particle-hole). }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added an image. It is not clear to me what would you like to change...

Comment: Image looks just fine, however, code can be far more concise  ... BTW, you use an ancient version of `pgfplots`, now is version `1.18` :-)

Comment: ...and you can use `\node[right]{t\textsuperscript{pair}}`  (and so on) for the label. Building everything with absolute coordinates should have been a pain. Look for example  my answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600850/add-text-to-spin-chain-with-tikz/600856#600856

Comment: Thanks Rmano, at least now the t_\perp looks nicer ahah :-)

Comment: Btw, if I switch to version 1.18, all the graphs remain the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look any different, but you can minimize the code and make it more readible by using scopes and `++()` notation:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm,thick]
            \draw (-0.5, 0) -- ++(3.0, 0) (-0.5, .7) -- ++(3,0);
            \draw[dashed] (-1, 0) -- ++(0.5,0) (2.5, 0) -- ++(0.5,0) (-1, .7) -- ++(0.5,0) (2.5, .7) --  ++(0.5,0);
            
            \begin{scope}
                \node[] at (0,1) {a)};
                \draw [dashed, red] (0,0) -- ++(0,.7);
                \draw [-stealth]  (0.05,-0.15) -- ++(-0.1,0.3);
                \draw [red] (-0.1,0.33) -- ++(0.1,0.1) -- ++(0.1,-0.1) node[anchor=south west,black] {t$_{\perp}$};
            \end{scope}
            
            \begin{scope}[xshift=2.25cm]
                \node[] at (0,1) {b)};
                \draw [-stealth] (0,-0.15) -- ++(-0.1,0.3);
                \draw [-stealth] (0.05,0.15) -- ++(0.1,-0.3);
                \draw [red] (-0.1,0.33) -- ++(0.1,0.1) -- ++(0.1,-0.1) node[anchor=south west,black] {{t\textsubscript{pair}}};
                \draw [dashed, red] (0,0) -- ++(0,.7);
            \end{scope}

            \begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
                \node[] at (0,1) {c)};
                \draw[dashed,red] (0,.35) ellipse (.4cm and .7cm);
                \draw [red] (0.1,0.3) -- ++(0.1,0.1) -- ++(0.1,-0.1) node[anchor=south west,black] {{t\textsubscript{sing}}};
                \draw [red] (-0.3,0.4) -- ++(0.1,-0.1) -- ++(0.1,0.1);
                \draw [-stealth]  (-0.05,0.15) -- (0.05,-0.15);
                \draw [-stealth] (0.05,0.55) -- (-0.05,0.85) ;
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: appreciate it :) I'll use this vesion instead!

Comment: `t$^{pair}$` is typeset as it says "t to the product of p, a, i, and r". Much better in this case `t\textsuperscript{pair}`... anyhow, +1

Comment: @Rmano Yes, you are right. I keep forgetting about these commands. I have edited the code accordingly.